How to get `.rowcount` on Azure Database Python script?
I need to make a python script using a query and params formatted as a list of dicts to use the execute function on the engine object.
The script that I have been trying only returns -1:
db_type = "mssql+pyodbc"
username = "sa"
password = "abcABC123"
host = "localhost"
port = "1433"
database = "tempdb"
driver = "ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"

query = """
    INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (:val)
"""

params = [
    {'val': 1},
    {'val': 2},
    {'val': 3},
    {'val': 4},
]

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text

engine = create_engine(f"{db_type}://{username}:{password}@{host},{port}/{database}?driver={driver}")
engine.connect()

with engine.begin() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(text(query), params)
    print(result.rowcount)

docker-compose.yml (for database)
version: "3.9"

services:
  TestDatabase:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: TestDatabase
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=abcABC123
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
      - MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True

It should print the number of rows inserted but nonmatter what I try I cannot get it to work. If anyone can point me in the right direction. I think its a problem with the dbapi?

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/481

Add below lines to your code to get total count of inserted rows to the SQL table:
total_inserted_rows = 0

with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        for param in params:
            result = connection.execute(query, **param)
            total_inserted_rows += result.rowcount
print(f"Total inserted rows: {total_inserted_rows}")

It will total count of inserted rows to the SQL table, here is the complete code for your reference:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import urllib
import sqlalchemy

server = '<serverName>'
database = '<dbName>'
username = '<userName>'
password = '<password>'
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
odbc_str = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;UID='+username+';DATABASE='+ database + ';PWD='+ password
connect_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_str)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connect_str)
query = text("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (:val)")
params = [{'val': 1}, {'val': 2}, {'val': 3}, {'val': 4}]
total_inserted_rows = 0
with engine.connect() as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        for param in params:
            result = connection.execute(query, **param)
            total_inserted_rows += result.rowcount
print(f"Total inserted rows: {total_inserted_rows}")

You will get the output as shown below:


your solution simply hits the database for each number of params. I am hoping to make as little requests as possible. The funny thing is when you run my code it actually works... it just returns 0. Therefore, your solution does not fix what I wanted it too. Thank you for trying.

After much research about the azure database I have come to the conclusion that it is impossible. I currently make the one request and if it succeeds I then return the number of items in dictionary. Less than ideal but works well enough.
